# Query from Firestore. Need to get list of objects

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Need to get list of objects based on LIST of parameters not only 1 parameter.

Step 1: we get list of uidUsers from one collection ONE and save it as a list
Step 2: in collection TWO I need to get only those documents(objects with values) where document is equal value from the list from step 1.

I wanted to filter documents by compare document name with uid in the list. But didn't find any solutions in API. 
And now maybe it is possible to save uidUser in the field of document so I could try to find by comparing key-value of document field with value from list. But i dont know how.

There is a small code i have

```
  public void getNeededUsers(List<String> uidList, UsersListCallback usersListCallback){
    Query query = db.collection(Consts.COLLECTION_USERS);
    for (String uid: uidList) {
        query.whereEqualTo("uid", uid);
    }
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot: task.getResult().getDocuments()){
            userList.add(snapshot.toObject(User.class));
        }
        usersListCallback.getUsers(userList);
    });
}
```

Comment: list of uidUsers contains all the uids from the database or only particular one? If it doesn't contains all uids, what is the condition of having those users in that list? You say "where document is equal value from the list" is equal to a property or how? Please add also you database structure and indicate the data that you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
public void getNeededUsers(List<String> uidList, UsersListCallback usersListCallback){
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < uidList.size(); i++){
    db.collection("Collection A").whereEqualTo("uid", uidList.get(i))
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                userList.add(documentReference.getId());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Error In Fetching Uid's" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            });
        }
```

Now userList will contain all the matched uid's. Now retrieve data from collection 2 based on these uid's.

By calling fetchData(userList);

```
public void fetchData(List<String> documentList)
{
for (int j = 0; j < documentList.size(); j++){
    db.collection("Collection B").whereEqualTo("uid", documentList.get(i))
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult())
                {
                    //Here you can fetch data or convert it to object
                }
            }
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
     }
}
```

Comment: Did that helped @BorisRuzanov ?

Comment: Yes Thank you very much!